# .click menu icon to slide in menu

Tags: jquery, menu, click, jquery-animate, width

I am trying to achieve a similar menu effect as shown on the
[etchapps website](http://etchapps.com/).

This is as close as I can get: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6av/6/)

```
$("#openMenu").click(function() {
    var menu = $("#menu");
    if ($(menu).is(":visible")) {
        $(menu).animate({
            width: 0
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(menu).hide();
        });
  } else {
     $(menu).show().animate({
       width: 200
      }, 1000); 
   }
});
```

Please help me combine these items to achieve my desired effect, Thanks!

Comment: what is ur requirement

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6av/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example site uses [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) instead of JavaScript for the desired effect. Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fDsy/1/). It should point into the right direction.

## HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <img src="http://m.liveperson.com/themes/images/menu-icon-hd-36-off.png" />
  <nav>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="work.html">Work</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
#menu img {
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .25s linear;
}
#menu nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
}
#menu.active nav {
  left: -20em;
  opacity: 0;
}
#menu.active img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

## JavaScript:

```
$("#menu img").click(function() {
    $("#menu").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Is it possible for the menu not to show behind the square icon? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know your question mentioned jQuery, but as we're dealing with how things are being displayed, it's a good idea to look to use CSS where possible.

Here's a demo of a working version, you'll need to check it in IE, but I'm fairly sure it'll be fine. In IE8, it'll toggle the menu rather than slide it in (search for 'graceful degradation' to find out why that's OK)

**HTML**

I tidied your html to make it follow a few more best practices.

**CSS**

I made it use transitions which have hardware support on mobile (smoother animations)

**JS**

Reduced to just toggle a class, see also CSS :target selector.

```
$(".navbar button").click(function() {
    var menu = $("ul").toggleClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymsHb/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: For some reason It works on jsFiddle but not on my actual page, My code is (i'm new to web-design!):

Comment: For some reason It works on jsFiddle but not on my actual page, My code is (i'm new to web-design!): http://jsfiddle.net/ymsHb/12/

Comment: @user2406220 here you go :) I just made the CSS and javascript selectors a bit more specific http://jsfiddle.net/ymsHb/13/

Comment: I'm using chrome and its still just showing the menu icon and not doing anything but it works in jsFiddle. I'm a bit confused

Comment: Check the CSS and JS aren't interfering with other parts of your site, you'll need to take a peek and see what's conflicting. Try removing things from your site temporarily until it works :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4fDsy/6/ Works in the fiddle but not when i view the page in a browser, exact same code. strange

Answer (score 0):

Using this jQuery plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation, I have modified ur fiddle. In this modified fiddle I added an external js file http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js

To use this plugin, simply add the required js within a script tag.